# How to merge OSM tiles from high zoom level to lower zoom level?

Tags: python, image, pyspark, openstreetmap, tile

### Some context

I am creating a heatmap from GPX data with spark. I managed to create OSM tiles on a zoom level 15 and now I want to merge them into a zoom level 14. I prefer to do it this way instead of recomputing the heatmap for each zoom level, because it takes hours (even with spark). This would save me a lot of computation time.

### What I have

On zoom level 15 I have object of type

```
tile_data_zoom_15 = [{tile_x: 7654, tile_y: 161, heatmap:[(x1, y1, count), (x2, y2, count), ...]}]
```

and I want to have he same data structure for `tile_data_zoom_15`

### Solution

So I do not have the solution, but what I get is that I need to translate every `(x1, y1)` into another pair but for the previous zoom level. On https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiletool they kind of explain the idea but not how the merging should happen in practice.

[image: merging osm tiles]

Any help would be more than welcome !

Comment: Did you already read https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames? It explains the correlation between tile numbers, zoom level and coordinates and how to calculate them.

Comment: Actually I found this a little before your answer and I was able to make it work! Not sure if it is worth answering my question, or perhaps it is better to delete?

Comment: Assuming this is not a duplicate you should try to answer your questions. It may help other users who encountered the same problem.